# Building Tensorflow C++ project outside the TensorFlow repo?

Tags: c++, compilation, tensorflow

So I installed Tensorflow [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620794/how-to-build-and-use-google-tensorflow-c-api). [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33622489/1079075) mentions that the project must be within the cloned local TensorFlow repo. Is there a way to have the project outside the repo?

Comment: Maybe something like this can help - run configure with this key :
./configure --prefix=/somewhere/else/than/usr/local

Comment: I am sorry. I am not sure what you mean by somewhere else. Do you mean the directory of my project?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no official way to build your code outside of the TF repo. You can, however, use [tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) project, that builds and installs TF C++ library for you and provides convenient CMake targets with all the necessary headers and link parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, you would just need to do the following:

1. Clone the tensorflow repository
2. `./configure` to your linking (enable CUDA, etc.)
3. Using `bazel build` build `//tensorflow:libtensorflow.so` and `//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so`.
4. Create a project of your own, *outside* the repository and link against the `.so`:s you just compiled, you would need the following options at compile/link time:

   ```
   -I/path/to/repo/tensorflow
   -L/path/to/repo/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow
   -ltensorflow_framework -ltensorflow_cc
   ```
5. Your `.hpp` and `.cpp` files can now use `tensorflow::Session`, and other classes by including the appropriate header files:

   ```
   #include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
   #include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
   ```

You might also need (for headers generated by protobuf compiler `protoc`):

```
-I/path/to/repo/tensorflow/bazel-genfiles/
```

As well as to dependent libraries (e.g. it complained about `nsync`):

```
-I/path/to/repo/tensorflow/bazel-tensorflow/external/nsync/public
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully built tensorflow-gpu dyanmic library, with Cmake and Visual Studio 2015, and now I'm able to put the project outside the TF repo.

1.git clone -b r1.7 --single-branch https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git

2.Cmake and select options with shared library and enable-gpu

3.build tensorflow.dll and tensorflow.lib with visual studio 2015

There will be some error during building, but it's easy to fix.
Leave a comment if you hope to know the details.