# Bazel doesn't let me use TensorShape constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, machine-learning, tensorflow, bazel

I am working on a TF project. I want to create a TF Tensor of a certain shape {batch_size,rows,cols,channels}.

Now doing this:

```
  tensorflow::Tensor T(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({1,rows,cols,channels}));
```

Should work as I have seen it work [here](https://gist.github.com/kyrs/9adf86366e9e4f04addb).

Now when I try to compile using bazel ( with the project created with the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620794/how-to-build-and-use-google-tensorflow-c-api))

However Bazel doesn't like it so it gives me this error:

> In instantiation of 'std::__cxx11::string* tensorflow::internal::Check_LTImpl(const T1&, const T2&, const char*) [with T1 = unsigned int; T2 = int; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string]':

EDIT:

[Full error here.](http://pastebin.com/RnDuC7Pb)

The Code in question [here](http://pastebin.com/qPYi0KbR) and [here](http://pastebin.com/ZZCBQHsN).

[The BUILD file.](http://pastebin.com/YuhiBUAn)

Comment: Can you include the complete compiler error? You're missing some important details.

Comment: I figured the source my error. In my function, I was using T.matrix<float>(). In that case, TF doesn't necessarily know the dimension. Later I use T_M(s,r,c,ch) and since the dimension is undetemined. It throws and error. Using T.tensor<float,4>() seems to solve this. Sorry for bothering you all.