# Is there way to package Tensorflow for c++ api?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I've been developing c++ project using a Tensorflow c++ api. it just execute created tensorflow's graph from Python. I build it using bazel with Tensorflow code now. But I think it's inefficient way.

I want just Tensorflow library and header files, and Just compile my project only using Cmake.

I know how to build shared library.

`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so` but this command just make a **libtensorflow.so** file. I can't find header files for build my project.

Is there way to package tensorflow library for c++? such as `mvn package` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build and use Google TensorFlow C++ api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620794/how-to-build-and-use-google-tensorflow-c-api)

Comment: @m8mble The questions are close, indeed. It seems to me more specific to CMake here. Should we ask for an extra tag or something in the title?

Comment: @EricPlaton Yes, this would atleast help. In any case, the question lacks distinction from the old one...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no official distributable C++ API package. There is, however, [tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) project that builds and installs TF C++ API for you, along with convenient CMake targets you can link against. According to your description, that may be just what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If your operating system is Debian or Ubuntu, you can download unofficial prebuilt packages with the Tensorflow C/C++ libraries. This distribution can be used for C/C++ inference with CPU, GPU support is not included:

https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging/releases

There are instructions written how to freeze a checkpoint in Tensorflow (TFLearn) and load this model for inference with the C/C++ API:

https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging/blob/master/README.md

Beware: I am the developer of this Github project.

As Floop already mentioned, his tensorflow_cc project is also a good alternative without packaging, especially if you want GPU support for the inference.

Answer (score 1):

You can build tensorflow with CMake. This also creates a TensorflowConfig.cmake, which you can integrate in your project

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake

*Little hint*: You have to build the shared lib, even if you do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two option: static linking and dynamic linking. 
If you want to dynamic link your c++ project to TensorFlow, all you need is a `--whole-archive` linker flag. The necessary header files are provided by a pip install.

Generating the library is basically

```
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mfpmath=both --config=cuda //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
bazel build -c opt --copt=-mfpmath=both --config=cuda //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
```

Having everything in place it is easy to run a TensorFlow graph in [C, C++, Go (GitHub project)](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference). See the linked project for these working examples in C, C++, Go.

Answer (score -1):

When building against the shared library, the headers I use are in `$PROJECT_HOME/bazel-genfiles`.

Adding `$PROJECT_HOME/bazel-genfiles` to the linker header list should be enough.

Comment: This is not enough.