# Errors when building TensorFlow with CMake on Windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, msbuild, cmake, windows-10

I am attempting a [TensorFlow CMake build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake) on Windows, but I'm running into problems.

First, I run

```
C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build>cmake .. -A x64 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
More? -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=C:/Program1/swigwin-3.0.12/swig.exe ^
More? -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:/Python3.5/python.exe ^
More? -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES=C:/Python3.5/libs/python35.lib ^
More? -Dtensorflow_ENABLE_GPU=ON ^
More? -DCUDNN_HOME="C:\Program1\cudnn\cuda"
```

and get the output

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED
-- Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED - Failed
-- Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0 (found suitable version "8.0", minimum required is "8.0")
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Python3.5/python.exe (found version "3.5")
-- Found PythonLibs: C:/Python3.5/libs/python35.lib (found version "3.5.0")
-- Found SWIG: C:/Program1/swigwin-3.0.12/swig.exe (found version "3.0.12")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/work/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/build
```

The only troubling line here is `-- Performing Test COMPILER_OPT_ARCH_NATIVE_SUPPORTED - Failed`, which I don't really know what it means or whether it's a serious problem. (*Is it?*)

Second, I run

```
MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj
```

and this gives me several errors:

```
"C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_gpu_kernels.vcxproj" (default target) (90) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_gpu_kernels.vcxproj]


"C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_kernels.vcxproj" (default target) (91) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  c:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\cuda_solvers.h(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cuda/include/cusolverDn.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\cholesky_op.cc) [C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_kernels.vcxproj]
  c:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\cuda_solvers.h(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cuda/include/cusolverDn.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\cuda_solvers.cc) [C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_kernels.vcxproj]
  c:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\external\eigen_archive\eigen\src\core\coreevaluators.h(1052): fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space (compiling source file C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\svd_op_float.cc) [C:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_kernels.vcxproj]

    696 Warning(s)
    4 Error(s)
```

I don't know relative to which folder MSBuild is looking for `cuda/include/cusolverDn.h`. I don't have any folder called `cuda` in `c:\work\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels`, and no file named `cusolverDn.h` exists anywhere in the `tensorflow` repository. (I do have the file `cusolverDn.h` in my CUDA install directory, though.) So,

*What can I do to make MSBuild find `cusolverDn.h`? And what can I do to prevent the compiler from running out of heap space?*

In a previous attempt to run the last command I also received the message

```
nvcc fatal   : Microsoft Visual Studio configuration file 'vcvars64.bat' could not be found for installation at 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/../..'
```

Some recommend [renaming a folder and a file in that folder](https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin/issues/3). I can't really verify that this works right now since the problem temporarily seems to have disappeared (maybe masked by the "compiler is out of heap space" problem, which I didn't have before...).

*Is renaming this file and this folder the correct solution?*

Answer (score 1):

As per [tensorflow instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake#step-by-step-windows-build) check the following:

- you must be running a 64 bit enabled Command Prompt for Visual Studio; you should run your msbuild.exe commands from such a prompt;
- install CUDNN's Nvidia zio file and append its /bin/ directory to your PATH environment variable, it should contains two entries similar to the following:

  - D:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin
  - D:\YOURCUDNNPATH\cuda\bin
- check whether both  `git` and `cmake` command are available in the PATH; check whether you could run those commands from your prompt;

Comment: that is the path to where you unzipped your cuDNN package, it must be the path to reach the cuDNN DLL file (just the path with no file name at the end).

Comment: I'm running all commands from `VS2015 x86 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt` (which I guess should be 64 bit enabled), I have the bin directories of both the CUDA installation and the CUDNN installation in my `PATH`, and I have `git` and `cmake` in my `PATH`. So those criteria are fulfilled. I'm still getting `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cuda/include/cusolverDn.h': No such file or directory` when running `MSBuild`, however.

Comment: Wiat a minute, how is `MSBuild` supposed to get the location of `cusolverDn.h` to begin with? That file is located in `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include`, but I never provide `MSBuild` with that path.

Comment: Set CUDDN to point one directory level up, i.e. ```'C:\Program1\cudnn\'```. Regarding your comment, when configuring with CMake it identified the CUDA position on file system (```Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0```), it should have added to include search path the  ```include``` subdir as well.

Comment: i meant the CUDDN_HOME env var

Comment: Actually, the `CUDDN_HOME` should be set to `C:\Program1\cudnn\cuda`, since CMake expects there to be an include folder in the directory pointed to by `CUDDN_HOME`. If I remove "`\cuda`", I get `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:215 (FILE):
  file COPY cannot find "C:/Program1/cudnn/include/cudnn.h".`. So it's weird that in the example on the _TensorFlow CMake build_ page, the path they provide ends with `cudnn`.