# Using tensorflow in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow

I know there are ways of using Tensorflow in C++ they even have a [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/) for it but I can seem to be able to get the library for it. I've checked the [build from source instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) but it seems to builds a pip package rather than a library I can link to my project. I also found a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@shiweili/building-tensorflow-c-shared-library-on-windows-e79c90e23e6e) but when I tried it out I ran out of memory and my computer crashed. My question is, how can I actually get the C++ library to work on my project? I do have these requirements, I have to work on windows with Visual Studio in C++. What I would love to is if I could get a pre-compiled DLL that I could just link but I haven't found such a thing and I'm open to other alternatives.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41071296

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment so I am writing this as an answer. 
If you don't mind using Keras, you could use the package [frugally deep](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep). I haven't seen a library myself either, but I came across frugally deep and it seemed easy to implement. I am currently trying to use it, so I cannot guarantee it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out neural2D from here:

https://github.com/davidrmiller/neural2d

It is a neural network implementation without any dependent libraries (all written from scratch).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best option is to use [cppflow](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow), an easy wrapper that I created to use Tensorflow from C++ easily.

You won't need to install anything, just download the TF C API, and place it somewhere in your computer. You can take a look to the [docs](https://serizba.github.io/cppflow/) to see how to do it, and how to use the library.

Answer (score -1):

The answer seems to be that it is [hard](https://github.com/guikarist/tensorflow-windows-build-script) :-(

Try [this](https://github.com/sitting-duck/stuff/tree/master/ai/tensorflow/build_tensorflow_1.14_source_for_Windows) to start. You can follow the latest instructions for [building from source on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows) up to the point of building the pip package. But don't do that - do this/these instead:

```
bazel -config=opt //tensorflow:tensorflow.dll 
bazel -config=opt //tensorflow:tensorflow.lib
bazel -config=opt tensorflow:install_headers
```

That much seems to work fine. The problems really start when you try to use Any of the header files - you will probably get compilation errors, at least with TF version >= 2.0. I have tried:

- Build the label_image example (instructions in the readme.md file)

  - It builds and runs fine on Windows, meaning all the headers and source are there somewhere
  - Try incorporating that source into Windows console executable: runs into compiler errors due to conflicts with std::min & std::max, probably due to Windows SDK.
- Include c_api.h in a Windows console application: won't compile.
- Include TF-Lite header files: won't compile.

There is little point investing the lengthy compile time in the first two bazel commands if you can't get the headers to compile :-(

You may have time to invest in resolving these errors; I don't. At this stage Tensorflow lacks sufficient support for Windows C++ to rely on it, particularly in a commercial setting. I suggest exploring these options instead:

- If TF-Lite is an option, [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dox1ZkFP-f4)
- [Windows ML/Direct ML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/) (requires conversion of TF models to ONNX format)
- [CPPFlow](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow)
- [Frugally Deep](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep)
- [Keras2CPP](https://github.com/gosha20777/keras2cpp)

UPDATE: having explored the list above, I eventually found the following worked best in my context (real-time continuous item recognition):

- convert models to ONNX format (use [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx) or [keras2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/keras-onnx)
- use Microsoft's [ONNX runtime](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime)

Even though Microsoft recommends using [DirectML](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectML) where milliseconds matter, the performance of ONNX runtime using DirectML as an execution provider means we can run a 224x224 RGB image through our Intel GPU in around 20ms, which is quick enough for us. But it was still hard finding our way to this answer