# GoogLeNet Implementation and Training using TensorFlow and C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm currently working on a project of image processing and my goal would ideally be to have GoogLeNet CNN using TensorFlow and C++ language. I don't want a pre trained CNN, i would like to train it myself.

I did a lot of research to find that a lot of things are available in Python with TensorFlow and that you can train a CNN using Python and export it for C++ or use other libraries like Caffe.

But i would really like to use Tensoflow and C++ language if it is possible !

What do you guys think about that ?

If some of you have ideas or beginning of tracks i can follow that would be so cool :)

Thank you !

Comment: What do you need to do with C++?

Comment: Implement and train my CNN if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow has a low-level API written entirely in C++ that you can find in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/).
Moreover, you can find an [image recognition example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image) in the official repository which uses the C++ API.

I think that you can find supplementary information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620794/how-to-build-and-use-google-tensorflow-c-api) StackOverflow question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! 
But you see in the image recognition example, they propose a pre trained CNN. I found a lot of sites dealing with pre trained networks and the only one i found which dealt with non trained network is this link : ttps://research.googleblog.com/2016/03/train-your-own-image-classifier-with.html but it is all in Python !

Comment: Typically you train your network using Python and you write the components that should be efficiently executed in C++. You can see this strategy also in the model released by Google: https://github.com/tensorflow/models

Comment: Yes that's what i figured people tend to use only Python to train. But may I ask why we generally train the networks using Python instead of C++ ? Is there a clear advantage using Python over C++ ?

Comment: It is incredible easier to manage the input data using Python by leveraging NumPy functions or pandas classes. Moreover, it is incredibly easier to write your code in Python. In this way, you can test your ideas without struggling with C++.

Comment: Ok thank you again for your answers and your help ! :)