# Install tensorflow using cmake

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake

I have just build tensorflow using VS2017 without GPU support in relase configuration :

```
cd tensorflow
cmake f:/lib/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
-DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=f:/swigwin-3.0.12/swig.exe ^
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python36_64/python.exe" ^
-DPYTHON_LIBRARIES="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python36_64/libs/python36.lib" ^
-Dtensorflow_WIN_CPU_SIMD_OPTIONS=/arch:AVX ^
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=g:/lib/install/tensorflow

MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxproj
```

Now using install project in VS solution If I select install project there is no error and I have got only 6 files copied :
 Répertoire de G:\Lib\install\tensorflow\bin

> ```
> 23/03/2018  15:43    <DIR>          .
> 23/03/2018  15:43    <DIR>          ..
> 23/03/2018  15:43        53 294 080 benchmark_model.exe
> 23/03/2018  15:43        53 574 656 compare_graphs.exe
> 23/03/2018  15:42        53 612 544 summarize_graph.exe
> 23/03/2018  15:39        53 297 664 tf_label_image_example.exe
> 23/03/2018  15:24        53 250 560 tf_tutorials_example_trainer.exe
> 23/03/2018  15:41        53 607 936 transform_graph.exe
>                6 fichier(s)      320 637 440 octets
>                2 Rép(s)  198 113 046 528 octets libres
> ```

There is no libs, no include. If I want to build my own C++ project using cmake I don't know how to use this install folder (there is no file tensorflow.cmake)

First question : Is my install regular ?

If answer to first question is yes :  to build my own c++ project must i copy all parameters from  tf_label_image_example projects?

Update my answer with @A. A comment : MSBuild /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo ALL_BUILD.vcxproj

> "F:\lib\build\tensorflow\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (cible par défaut) (1) ->
>   "F:\lib\build\tensorflow_beam_search_ops.vcxproj" (cible par défaut)
>   (2) -> "F:\lib\build\tensorflow\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.vcxproj"
>   (cible par défaut) (3) ->
>   "F:\lib\build\tensorflow\pywrap_tensorflow_internal_static.vcxproj"
>   (cible par défaut) (4) ->
>   "F:\lib\build\tensorflow\tf_core_kernels.vcxproj" (cible par défaut)
>   (130) -> (ClCompile cible) ->
>   f:\lib\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\training_ops.cc(1341): fatal
>   error C1060: espace du tas insuffisant pour le compilateur
>   [F:\lib\build\tensorflow\tf_core_kernels.vcxproj]
>
> ```
> 47 Avertissement(s)
> 1 Erreur(s)
> ```

It's in french (my vs2017 is in english but it seems that 's not for console tools  : only one [error c1060](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1060) :compiler is out of heap space.The operating system or run-time library cannot fill a request for memory.

If I run install (in vs solution)  only 6 exe files are copied :

> 1>------ Build started: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Release x64
>   ------ 1>-- Install configuration: "Release" 1>-- Up-to-date: G:/Lib/install/tensorflow/bin/tf_tutorials_example_trainer.exe 1>--
>   Up-to-date: G:/Lib/install/tensorflow/bin/tf_label_image_example.exe
>   1>-- Up-to-date: G:/Lib/install/tensorflow/bin/transform_graph.exe
>   1>-- Up-to-date: G:/Lib/install/tensorflow/bin/summarize_graph.exe
>   1>-- Up-to-date: G:/Lib/install/tensorflow/bin/compare_graphs.exe 1>--
>   Up-to-date: G:/Lib/install/tensorflow/bin/benchmark_model.exe
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

In relasewithdebug info nothing is copied but tf_core_kernel.lib is missing (error c1060)

thanks for your(s) answer(s)

Comment: You have build only the examples. You can try to build all `MSBuild /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo ALL_BUILD.vcxproj` - 
 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake

Comment: or `cmake.exe --build .` or http://www.shaneahmed.com/2017/07/build-tensorflow-on-windows.html

Comment: now I think there is no install procedure using cmake. problem is similar in this post (2 years old https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620794/how-to-build-and-use-google-tensorflow-c-api)

Comment: Use `Bazel` to build Tensorflow instaed of `Cmake`. Follow the instructions mentioned on [Tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows). Thanks!