# TensorFlow C++ prebuilt repo for CentOS/Fedora/Red Hat

Tags: tensorflow, centos, package, redhat

I need TensorFlow prebuilt library for **CentOS** as all of my servers are CentOS, however, I can find only the prebuilt for Ubuntu on the official tensorflow.org web site: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#available-packages

Already googled but couldn't find any repos. I tried to build with bazel as guided on tensorflow.org but it's just taking too long to build, hours! **Any updated CentOS/Fedoda/Red Hat repos with tensorflow package available?** Personal repos are OK.

Edit:
The official TensorFlow prebuilt is Python only, this is sad. I put down my expectation a bit, TensorFlow C++ repo for Ubuntu is also OK, I can create Ubuntu server, any TensorFlow C++ Ubuntu PPA?

Comment: i temporary created a ubuntu server to use, but i still want centos/redhat

Comment: it turned out that the prebuilt for ubuntu is for python only, what is google doing? no c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems no prebuilt TensorFlow C++ library available, **either download or through Linux repos**. Even the official prebuilt library by Google on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip is prebuilt for Python.

The library in Docker image provided on tensorflow.org https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker is also for Python only.

There are guides how to build TensorFlow C++ libary here:

- Build with normal Bazel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43920376/5581893
- Build with CMake and Bazel: https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc

The one with normal Bazel build process requires manual copying header files and .so files to proper directories. The one with CMake & Bazel makes everything available and ready to use. However, the build process is EXACTLY very slow, a few hours (~4 hours on my 2-core test server).

If one doesn't mind using Docker, there are Docker images with ready-to-use C++ headers & libs: https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc#docker